# Cmd stops working. (program crashes)

Tags: class, cmd

I want to make market items listing program. I am having trouble with the code. Here it is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

char n = '\n';

class shop
{
public:
void setItem(int a, string b, float c){
itemCode = a;
itemName = b;
itemPrice  = c;
}
int getCode(string a){
    cout<< a<<itemCode<<n;
    //return itemCode;
}
string getName(string b){
    cout<< b<<itemName<<n;
    //return itemName;
}
float getPrice(string c){
    cout<< c<<itemPrice<<n;
    //return itemPrice;
}
void getAll (string a,string b,string c){
    getCode(a);
    getName(b);
    getPrice(c);
}
private:
    int itemCode;
    string itemName;
    float itemPrice;
};

int main()
{
string daiktas;
int kodas;
float kaina;
while(1){
cout<< "Iveskite daikto pavadinima: "<<n;
cin>> daiktas;
cout<< "Iveskite daikto koda: "<<n;
cin>> kodas;
cout<< "Iveskite daikto kaina: "<<n;
cin>> kaina;

shop kodas1;
kodas1.setItem(kodas, daiktas, kaina);
kodas1.getAll("Kodas: " , "Preke: ", "Kaina: ");
}
}
```

After entering second `cin` (kodas), I get cmd "has stopped working", before that program `cout`'s : getName and getCode;
Why is it not working?

Answer (score 0):

```
// terrible code, don't use
int getCode(string a){
    cout<< a<<itemCode<<n;
    //return itemCode;
}
string getName(string b){
    cout<< b<<itemName<<n;
    //return itemName;
}
float getPrice(string c){
    cout<< c<<itemPrice<<n;
    //return itemPrice;
}
```

That's your issue right there. You're returning garbage. Which is fine in the case of plain types, but that `string` right there will try to get released at the end of your loop because it goes out of scope -- and bam, you corrupted the stack. In fact gcc even tells you as much:

> *** Error in `./prog': double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x08627a40 ***

Simply remove the comments to have the useless `return` actually return something real (or make them `void` since nobody seems to care about the thing they're returning anyway) and it works "fine". As fine as that code can work... At least it won't act as malware and corrupt your users' memory.

Comment: I just saw my first article :D. "WTF" :D. I was beginner... + programming culture. No one do like me here. Good luck Coders ;). Sorry!